# htaccess 301 redirect, main site moving into a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying really hard to grasp htaccess, but I am having a hard time figuring this one out.

Let's say I have http://www.example.com.

I am planning on moving the entire site into a folder like so http://www.example.com/folder/

I created a folder and moved everything in it. How do I make sure that if someone finds me through google, they will be redirected to the correct page.

For instance, http://www.example.com/view.php?id=5 becomes http://www.example.com/folder/view.php?id=5

Thanks for any help you might give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect every request from **example.com** to **example.com/folder** including css, js, html, php etc files then use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. Is there anyway I can redirect traffic going to example.com/view.php?id=1 to example.com/folder/view.php?id=1 so if that a customer goes to the first url, it still shows a page and not a 404?

Comment: Bastien, `example.com/view.php?id=1` should redirect to `example.com/folder/view.php?id=1` with the rule above.  If it does do that and returns a 404, can you verify that view.php exists in the folder directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, try:

```
RewriteEngine on
# make sure the requested URI doesn't go to an existing  file/directory (e.g. starts with /folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# make sure the requested URI goes to an existing file/directory inside /folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working for me. It redirects it to http://www.example.com/folder//folder//folder//folder// and so on

Comment: does /folder/ exist? otherwise you can add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/` right underneath RewriteEngine on